# Helper class with dependency is correct design or not?

Tags: java

This question arise to differentiate util class from helper class.

I think helper class can have complex fields where as util classes should contain static methods only.  Do you think below example is fine as an helper class? or Helper class cannot contain any dependency?
Eg.

```
class BusinessDataHelper(){
     private BusinessDataService service;
     public Result getData(int id){
            service.getData(id)
      }
}
```

What my understanding with helper class is to reduce duplicate code by adding methods which can be used by multiple classes into helper class. and add helper class a dependency for all such class which want to use getData method in above example.

Comment: A little more context would help us answer this question more thoroughly, but based on what I can see: I would suggest against doing it this way.  It seems strange to have to create a new `BusinessDataHelper` just to use a helper method.  Is it possible in this situation to send the `BusinessDataService` to a static method as a second parameter?

Answer (score 0):

No, that certainly is not a helper method. What you have there is a getter.

Let me give you an example of a helper method:

```
class Example {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int num1 = 4;
        int num2 = 5;
        System.out.println("We're going to be adding to numbers!");
        System.out.println("The sum of the two numbers is " + add(num1, num2));
    }

    public static int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

So obviously, this is an oversimplified version. You wouldn't ever need a separate method for adding, because it is such a simple action. But imagine you are working with a lot of lists and you need to find the average of the numbers in that list. You could create one method at the bottom called `averageList` which takes an `ArrayList<Integer>` as a parameter and returns an `int` that is the average. That way, every time you need the average value of the list, you could just called the method, `averageList(myList)` and get the average value, instead of having to type out all of the math that you'd have to do to get the average every time.

So for example, your averaging method could be:

```
public static int averageList(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int x = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        x += list.get(i);
    }
    return (x / list.size());
}
```

If you didn't have the helper method, you'd have to type those 5 lines every time you wanted to get the average. Having a method you can just call makes things much simpler.

I hope that helps. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion , the intention using helper class is adding functionalities to the application(not the core functionality of the application) like transforming data from object to other kind of object,a date converter helper for converting a date to timestamp to save in a particular database.Kind of a reusable component encapsulating generic operations.

However util class specifically has static methods to define re-used functions like the Collections class in java.

Answer (score 0):

An helper class should contain functions to help the service (class) that is being helped. Helper containing other services as dependencies does not look clean, it can call utility classes though. An utility class is more generic that it spans to help a package or a project.

An example helper class:

```
class BusinessDataService(){
     private BusinessDataHelper helper;
     .......
}
```